# htaccess rewrite rule remove subdirectory and .php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to rewrite the url of my web and make it hide subfolder and the .php extension, like this:

original : http://192.168.100.5/project/controller/report.php?unit=1&year=2021

goal : http://192.168.100.5/project/report?unit=1&year=2021

My current rules which doesnt work

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller/$1.php [L]
```

How to achieve this? thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 2 `.htaccess` files.

site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# forward everything to controller/ if not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* controller/$0 [L]
```

`controller/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add .php extension internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but it doesnt work whenever i try to access http://192.168.100.5/project/report it is always object not found

Comment: and also it make me cannot access image folder inside my project folder which i need to be able to access

Comment: ok please try my updated code in site root .htaccess